# How to prevent python BeautifulSoup from replacing escape sequences with hex codes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup in python script that helps me avoid manual work in mass updates in IBM IDA (Infosphere Data Architect) ldm (Logical Data Model) files which are actually xml. It works fine for me except for some side effect. description attribute in xml can contain some formatting  with control characters encoded as escape sequences like `&#xD`, `&#xA`, `&#x9`. On output in my script they are converted to hex `0D` `0A` `09`. I do not know how to avoid it. To illustrate the effect I simplified my script so that it just reads the model and writes it out to another file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import os

source_modlel_file_name="TestModel.ldm"
target_model_file_name="TestModel_out.ldm"

with open(source_modlel_file_name,'r',encoding="utf-8",newline="\r\n") as source_model_file:
    source_model = source_model_file.read()

soup_model=BeautifulSoup(source_model, "xml")

with open(target_model_file_name, "w",encoding="utf-8",newline="\r\n") as file:
    file.write(str(soup_model))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use custom formatter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter


class CustomAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            v = v.replace("\r", "&#xD;")
            v = v.replace("\n", "&#xA;")
            v = v.replace("\t", "&#x9;")
            yield k, v


xml_doc = """<test>
    <data description="Some Text &#xD; &#xA; &#x9;">
        some data
    </data>
</test>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

print(soup.prettify(formatter=CustomAttributes()))
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
 <data description="Some Text &#xD; &#xA; &#x9;">
  some data
 </data>
</test>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej.
Your patch is working.
But what I would prefer is some more general solution. Not to convert back what BeautifulSoup converted, but to disable this kind of conversion.

With this approach I need to know the full list of &# ... ; sequences and decode them back in custom formatter.

Also I am a bit concerned about HTMLFormatter module. According to the name it is designed for HTML, but I am working with XML. Not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: My main point is that with my script I would not like to touch something that has no relation to changes I want to do.

For example I need to remove label attribute for all columns in some specific table, but as a side effect I get some formatting changes in whole model, in tables which are completely not under my scope.